# Reverse Zoomin Animation with some given time gap for imageview

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, zooming

I wanted to reverse the zoom in animation with some time delay before reversing animation below is the code that works for reverse with infinite, but i need to set some time gap before having reverse of animation

zoom_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true" >
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:duration="5000"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="2"
    android:toYScale="2" >
</scale>
```

zoomout.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true" >
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="5000"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0.5"
    android:toYScale="0.5" >
</scale>
```

This is my activity with animation

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String TAG= "MainActivity";
Animation zoomin, zoomout; //declared as public
private final int ANIM_HOLD_LENGTH = 2000;
 ImageView imageView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    zoomin = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoomin);
    zoomout = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoomout);

    imageView.setAnimation(zoomin);


    zoomin.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d(TAG,"onAnimationStart--");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d(TAG,"onAnimationRepeat--");

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(final Animation arg0) {
            Log.d(TAG,"onAnimationEnd--");
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d(TAG,"onAnimationEnd-- run");
                    imageView.startAnimation(zoomout);

                }
            }, ANIM_HOLD_LENGTH);


        }
    });

    zoomout.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
            Log.d(TAG,"zoomout onAnimationStart--");

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
            Log.d(TAG,"zoomout onAnimationEnd--");

            imageView.startAnimation(zoomin);


        }
    });
}



 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally below change in zoomout.xml helped to resolve issue

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >
    <scale
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="5000"
        android:fromXScale="2"
        android:fromYScale="2"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="1" >
    </scale>

</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add delay like this

```
long delayTimeInMilliseconds = 1000;

Handler handler = new Handler();

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // here you can start your reverse animation
    }
}, delayTimeInMilliseconds);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply omer, i can do this but i could not find any method to hold and play reverse animation

Comment: you can create another zoom_in_reverse.xml for reverse animation and start in onAnimationEnd of zoom_in by adding delay

Comment: I did the same but image view is going back to normal place then starting that zoom_in_reverse animation

Comment: can u show your code. also did you set fillAfter property to true?

Comment: updated my code on edit .can you please see. this will reverse animation not from the zoomin completed position .hope u understand the issue

Comment: you zoom in imageView from 1 to 2 but in zoom out animation you  zoom out imageView from 1 to 0.5 that why it is not working. you need to change android:fromXScale="1.0" to android:fromXScale="2.0" and android:toXScale="0.5" to android:toXScale="1" and similarly for Y

Answer (score 0):

There is a much cleaner and better solution. Instead of splitting the animation in 2 different xml files and using animation listeners try merging them into one file zoom.xml like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true" >
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="5000"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="2"
    android:toYScale="2" />
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="5000"
    android:startOffset="5500"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0.5"
    android:toYScale="0.5" />
</set>
```

Notice that in second scale i added startOffset property. Which means that if you want the second animation to start immidiately after the first one you should set this property the duration of the first animation(5000 mils). In our case we set it as duration of the first animation(5000 mils) + your offset (500 mils). Then you just simply write

```
imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
zoom = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoom);
imageView.setAnimation(zoom);
```

Done!

Comment: Thanks Amish for your detailed answer,i will try this way too and see how it works

Comment: Check the updated xml. There was a redundant repeat mode that i did not notice.